# Can't boot Ubuntu from salvaged drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

Long story short, a Panel PC connected to some industrial machines failed. (It died because of a power surge.) I recovered the SSD and after cloning it to a USB drive with [Etcher](https://etcher.balena.io/), I attempted to boot it inside a VM and ended up on grub rescue "error:file not found".

Upon mounting the filesystem inside a Live Boot instance I discovered that the root contained only `/lost+found`, `/srv`, `/sys`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/var` and three files (`initrd.img`, `initrd.image.old`, `vmlinuz`).

Furthermore, `/boot` and every other folder were instead inside `/srv`.

- Is this folder structure common in any way?
- How can fix this?

Comment: When you say "_every other folder_" do you mean that every single directory in the system was directly underneath `/srv` regardless of where it should have been in the original filesystem? If so, that feels like massive filesystem corruption/failure

Comment: Yes, every directory other than the ones I listed was under /srv. Data seems intact though, I will try restoring directories to see if I can boot it up.

Comment: If every single directory has been flattened to a list under `/srv` I think you'll have a hard time restoring them to the right place. (For example, on my Debian-based system I've got at least six directories called `zone`, and 29 called `man1`.)